# Подредактировать treeview

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть на сайте дерево.

[Вот](http://akvarel-n.com.ua/stationery/63) как оно должно работать по идее. Т.е. раскрыта та ветка, у которой `id=63`. Но вот если перейти на [вторую страницу](http://akvarel-n.com.ua/stationery/63/2) данной группы, то дерево сворачивается.

Как это подправить? Я так понял, что скрипт берет адрес и по нему раскрывает нужную группу.

[Вот код](http://code.google.com/p/styleshop/source/browse/trunk/yii/yii/Fashion/assets/e651ac65/jquery.treeview.js?r=216).

Comment: да именно так и есть, чтобы меню оставалось раскрытым надо либо грузить аяксом, либо в ссылке указывать раскрытые блоки.

Comment: @FLK а как то можно передавать этому скрипту уже обрезанный адрес (без номера страницы) ?

Answer (score 1):

Могу только предположить, что с толку сбивает последний параметр ссылки (номер страницы). Расшифрую: раскрытые блоки у вас имеют класс "collapsable", этот класс добавляется ориентируясь на тот самый параметр "id=63", который в ссылке передается последним.  Если очень примитивно, то, например, как-то так:

```
<li <?php echo (GET['id'] == 63 ? 'class="collapsable"' : false);?>>Принадлежности для письма и черчения.</li>
```

Теперь возможны несколько вариантов "сбоя". Если вы в mod_rewrite задали правило перенаправления всех ссылок на index.php и парисите URI сами, то возможно, что не учитываете, что последний параметр - это уже не id, с которым надо делать сравнение. Второй вариант - вы прописали отдельные правила, но так же не учли передаваемый параметр с номером страницы.

Comment: Пишу на Kohana. Есть роут в бутстрапе 

Route::set('category', '<controller>/<id>(/<page>)', array('controller' =>'stationery|materials|souvenirs|school','id' => '[0-9]+', 'page' => '[0-9]+'))

Я вижу решение в обрезании этого параметра /page при передаче его в jQuery. Только есть одна проблема, я JS не знаю вообще и не могу разобраться, где бы что подправить, что бы обрезался адрес

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал примерно так:

```
$('#leftmenu a').each(function(){
    if(location.href.indexOf(this.href) !== -1){
        //раскрыть ветку
    }
});
```

Comment: Если можно, поподробнее. С JS  знаком очень издалека(